# Grouping by incremental values in SQL

Tags: sql, grouping

Assume I have a table similar to this

| CustomerID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 17.12 |
| 2 | 427.25 |
| 3 | 52.23 |
| 4 | 1542.23 |
| 5 | 72564.2 |

The data I'm using has around 130K entries where the values range from 0.01 up to a max of around 80K

What I am attempting to do is group counts of customers by increments of value (every 50)  and then provide the sum of value for that count of customers.

for example;

| Customer count | Group | Total value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | <50 | 327.30 |
| 7 | 50-100 | 601.20 |
| 23 | 100-150 | 3103.12 |

Typically I would assign each customer a value range manually, something like this

case when value < 50 then '<50'
when value between 50 and 100 then '50-100'

And so on, then aggregate based on that assigned grouping.

Because I have a large range of value, I'm not really keen on writing this when statement out 1 million times :P I figure there is hopefully a quicker way to say please just group it in value increments of 50?

Its not that using a case when statement doesn't work, I figure there may be a more efficient way to solve my problem that I'm just not thinking of.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a cursor and a temp table or a table parameter. It'd be memory and processor intensive but if this won't be running that often its probably the most efficient coding wise.
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/sql-server-cursor/
https://datatofish.com/temporary-table-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Heres an example of a while loop with parameters that would get the data you want.

```
CREATE TABLE #CustomerIntervalAggregates (
    CustomerCount INT,
    IntervalGroup VARCHAR(20),
    Total DECIMAL,
)

DECLARE @Interval INT = 10
Declare @CurrentInterval Int = @Interval
DECLARE @CustomerCount INT
DECLARE @Total DECIMAL
DECLARE @Max INT = (SELECT Max([Value]) from CustomerValues)
WHILE ( @CurrentInterval <= @Max)
BEGIN
    SELECT @CustomerCount = COUNT(CustomerID), @Total = SUM([Value]) from CustomerValues where [Value] > @CurrentInterval - @Interval and [Value] < @CurrentInterval
    Insert into #CustomerIntervalAggregates VALUES (@CustomerCount,  CAST(@CurrentInterval - @Interval as varchar) + ' - ' + CAST(@CurrentInterval as varchar), @Total)
    SET @CurrentInterval  = @CurrentInterval  + @Interval
END


select * from #CustomerIntervalAggregates
drop table #CustomerIntervalAggregates
```

Answer (score 0):

with t1 as (select customerid, value, trunc((Value+50)/50)as grp From cust_txn)
Select count(customerid) over (partition by grp) as count,
grp,
sum(value) over (partition by grp) as total_value from t1;

Just give a try using above idea, you can get n number of groups. Dynamic range name can be displayed something like like (grp-1)x50||’to‘||grpx50